# Handling Unexpected return data in ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, db2

I'm working with an old AS/400 application which uses DB2 as the underlying database.

I'm doing some `SELECT`'s to get data out. There is a field called `OHOREF` which means `Order Header Order Reference`... ie. it's the order number's reference number for a give order. We use this to link website orders to order numbers generated by our vendor application. In the vendor's database guide, this field is listed as:

```
|  Field | Type | Length | Dec | Req. |                   Text                    |   
+--------+------+--------+-----+------+-------------------------------------------+
| OHOREF |  A   |   15   |     |      | Customer/Suppliers Order Number Reference |
```

This seems to indicate this field is stored as an integer value, constrained to be no longer than 15 digits, and no decimal place allowed. So, like: 123456789012345

This vendor is very unhelpful and tries to "guard" their "IP" and does not provide better docs than I already have. (*sigh*)

The problem I'm facing, is when using:

```
int ohoref = resultSet.getInt(columnNumber);
```

I'm finding, when there is no reference number, this column is not null, but instead is max filled with padded spaces `" "`. So, like `"               "`. This results in a `Data type mismatch` exception being thrown. I do not know what field type `"A"` means in the table above, and I assume it has a special meaning for the vendor.

Is there no more elegant solution to dealing with this scenario other than to select **everything** out as a `String`? This seems awful, and makes the code have to do manual conversions all over the place, increasing potential risk of getting it wrong and/or causing problems elsewhere. Is type `A` a String or an `Integer`?

Comment: Can you just skip thos column? Is it used? Can you treat it as varchar?

Comment: can't skip it because something like 80% of the orders have this field populated and 20% don't. So it's an unknown until runtime. Now that I'm thinking about it... I suppose I could change `ohoref` to type `Integer` instead of `int` and this way I could `catch` the `exception` and then just do nothing, effectively leaving `ohoref` uninitialized and therefore `null`, which is much more preferred over a bunch of padded spaces... still feels hacky though...

Comment: The question is not how much is it set but how much is it used in code? If it is just filled with spaces, it does not bring much value. It looks like padding. You should review the code that uses this column and find out, if it is worthy to care about it. Could it be some unused relict? I think that you will be able to skip spaces-only values.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean by "often", as-in if the code does math on the number or something?... this piece of code takes these values out of the DB2 (using ohoref as one of the unique identifiers) and does some logic, then eventually puts these values into a mysql database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say what your vendor means by the `A` data type but generally speaking I would expect to see `I` for an integer column. `A` is likely to stand for "alphanumeric", which isn't really a data type but rather the contents description, for which the data type would be `CHAR(15)` (based on the fact that empty values contain 15 spaces).

To be certain you could find out the actual data type from `java.sql.ResultSetMetaData`.

Comment: I didn't think about `ResultSetMetaData` This may be helpful. Regarding the type `A`. Well, their database guide has every column in every table listed as either type `A` or type `P`.

Comment: Turned out to be a `Char` field... they also use `VARCHAR` for similar fields but all seem to get padded with spaces, both when data is present and when it should be null. So `|1234           |` ....

Comment: @mustaccio is right.  A is alphanumeric.  ie character.  Fixed length so you'll have it padded with spaces. P is packed decimal.  The "packed" really doesn't matter to you, it's just how the DB stores it.  The JDBC will return it to you as a fixed decimal numeric.

Comment: @Charles thank you for the additional information. Is it correct to assume this is DB2 stuff (the A and P) and not vendor-specific (ie. my app's vendor)? (I googled DB2 data types and got all the normal results, INT BIGINT, etc).

Comment: @SnakeDoc, well...let's call it OS stuff. :)  As the OS and it's built in RDBMS was around before DB2.  The DB in the AS/400 and it's predecessor the System/38 originally didn't have a name it was and is just part of the OS.  IBM just started calling it DB2/400.  There isn't a common code base between DB2 LUW / DB2 for i / DB2 for z/OS.  Though IBM has done a decent job of keeping them compatible.  As a final FYI, note that the packed decimal is also used on the mainframe (z/OS).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know this might help or not but give this a try,

you can  get the `InputStream` objects pertaining to that column using below methods,

```
   rs.getAsciiStream(columnNumber)
   rs.getCharacterStream(columnNumber)
```